# JSON nested property as not nested

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

Is that possible in case where i have for instance

```
class DefaultFruit {
  taste: String
}

class Fruit {

  fruit: DefaultFruit
  color: String
}
```

to provide some annotation @JSON annotation which convert the object structure

to:

```
{
color: "",
taste: "",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can annotate the `fruit` property/field with [@JsonUnwrapped](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) and the DefaultFruit properties will be serialized/deseralized alongside the Fruit properties.

```
public static class DefaultFruit {
    public String taste;
}

public static class Fruit {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public DefaultFruit fruit;
    public String color;
}

@Test
public void serialize_unwrapped() throws Exception {
    Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
    fruit.color = "red";
    fruit.fruit = new DefaultFruit();
    fruit.fruit.taste = "sweet";
    assertThat(mapper.writeValueAsString(fruit),
               equalTo("{\"taste\":\"sweet\",\"color\":\"red\"}"));
}
```

Comment: True I tried, but it didn't have any effect, though I use another Json annotations like @JsonFormat and they work. hmm...

Comment: that's odd, I've just tried it and it does seem to work for me, at least for serialization.

Comment: Maybe I have wrong configuration/ jackson version. Anyway it is a good answer.